# How to design expandable listview with different childs

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

[image]

This is how my screen should look like. The problem for me here is, I should pass User object to adapter and fill those fields with user object fields. How could I know which field to update if I create child layout with one TextView?

Is it a better idea to create for example DetailsViewHolder, AddressViewHolder, etc? Or I can create details.xml with 6 Edittexts? but I don't think that's a good idea, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView is best for long lists that may change with time. For your situation I wouldn't recommend using a ListView at all, but rather a simple LinearLayout. It is much easier to work with and gets the job done perfectly. If you need scrolling, just wrap the LinearLayout inside a ScollView.

Comment: Hmm. You could still use the ExpandableListView then, and just add each line item  (ex: Country, City, etc) as a child of the parent. You don't need to have details.xml with 6 EditTexts. You can have the parents as {"Details", "Address", "Billing Address"}, and then the children of "Details" be "First Name", "Last Name", etc}. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Also, you can still use a LinearLayout and just have the header elements be clickable with an animation to expand/collapse the child elements container.

Comment: yep, those parents are called groups in expandable listview. I fill those things manually, Group names and it's fields (children) ...but how can I know which children to update with which user object field? If you understand what I'm asking?

Comment: in getChildView(), you can call getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) to get the data to fill it in.

Comment: should I then compare, for example:  if( (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).equals("First Name") ... then update editText with user.getFirstName(); and the same way for all those fields  ...or is there a better way?

Comment: No. You would do something like this: If (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 0) { edtText.setText(user.getFirstName()) ... } if (groupPosition == 0 && childPosition == 1) { edtText.setText(user.getLastName)}; Alternatively you can use a case-switch which would be a lot cleaner: switch(groupPosition)[ case 0: switch(childPosition)[ case 0 ... case 1 ....];  case1: switch(childPosition)[ case 0 ... case 1 ....];] Also, you should use constants for the parents since they're fixed (ie if groupPosition == POSITION_DETAIL instead of groupPosition == 0).

Comment: Yup, yup, thanks man! It also requires a lot of switching and checking, but I assume it's the best solution in this case. Thank you for clearing this up, cheers!

Comment: My please :) feel free to accept the answer if you're happy with it.